# Adding EditText to a xml file not working

Tags: java, android-edittext, scrollview

I have been working on an app and can't get EditText into an xml file.

I had it working, then I added a ScrollView and it didn't work at all so I deleted it and now it spreads out the groups throughout the screen, and I can't fix it.

## PlayScreen.java

```java
/**
 * Created by Gavin on 8/10/2016.
 */
public class PlayScreen extends Activity {

    public EditText numberOP;
    private RelativeLayout layout;

    private int i = 0;
    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 1;
    private int z = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        setContentView(R.layout.layout_play);

        numberOP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number_of_players);

        layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_play_id);

    }

    public void onEnterClickOne(View view) {

        /**if(textView != null) {
            layout.removeView(textView);
        }
        if(editText != null) {
            layout.removeView(editText);
        }*/

        int b = 0;

        if(i+y+x+z != 0) {
            for (b = 0; b < i + y + x + z * 100; b++) {
                System.out.println(b);
                View v = findViewById(b);
                if (v != null) {
                    layout.removeView(v);
                }
            }
        }

        i = 0;
        x = 0;
        y = 1;
        z = 1;

        if (numberOP.getText().toString().length() > 0) {

            int length = Integer.parseInt(numberOP.getText().toString())*2;

            for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    x++;
                    TextView textView = new TextView(PlayScreen.this);
                    textView.setId(x*30);
                    textView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                    textView.setText(String.format("Group: %s", Integer.toString(x)));
                    textView.setTextSize(20);
                    textView.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
                    layout.addView(textView);
                }
                EditText editText = new EditText(PlayScreen.this);
                    editText.setId(i+1);
                    editText.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                if(y == 1) {
                    editText.setHint("Partner 1");
                    y++;
                } else if(y == 2) {
                    editText.setHint("Partner 2");
                    y--;
                }
                layout.addView(editText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## layout_play.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="#f7f7f7"
    android:id="@+id/layout_play_id"
    android:padding="25dp">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/choose_your_partners"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="31sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/editTextTwo" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/number_of_groups"
        android:id="@+id/number_of_players"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextTwo"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_1_text"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:id="@+id/playButton"
        android:onClick="onEnterClickOne"
        android:layout_below="@+id/number_of_players"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Also, if you have any suggestions for ScrollView, that'd be awesome. Thanks.

[The Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqTbZ.png)

Comment: What do you mean by not working, do you mean EditText not showing or what?

Comment: It spreads the TextView and EditText throughout the screen, instead of right on top of eachother.

Comment: I have added a picture to the post showing the problem.

Comment: add `!` right before start square bracket you added for the link to show the picture here rather than new tab, I can't edit it because it's too short :)

Answer (score 0):

For such kind of view component, it is better to use `LinearLayout` with vertically orientation, to easily put the view component inside this.

**RelativeLayout:**
RelativeLayout enables you to specify how child views are positioned relative to each other. The position of each view can be specified as relative to sibling elements or relative to the parent.

[image]

**LinearLayout:**
LinearLayout is a view group that aligns all children in either vertically or horizontally.
[image]

Comment: That fixed it. I also added a ScrollView within that class and it seems to work.

Comment: That is good, if the answer solved your problem or helped you, please accept the answer and vote up. Thanks